# Pasar variables PHP a JSON

Tags: php, json

Estoy haciendo una app para test los cuales los tengo en una BD mysql. Quisiera saber si sería posible con JSON encode hacer un SELECT en php de la base de datos y pasarlos a JSON. El código lo he sacado de un ejemplo y hace una llamada al archivo "quiz.json" para obtener los datos, el cual me gustaría que no se leyese y que directamente leyese el array PHP.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/jquery.quiz.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- header -->
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bg-header d-flex justify-content-start align-items-md-center flex-column flex-md-row align-items-sm-start">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <h1 class="titolo">GEOGRAPHY QUIZ</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- main -->
<section class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="quiz_container"></div>
    <div class="code_example">
      <pre class="prettyprint linenums">&lt;script&gt;
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var pathJson = window.location.pathname.replace(//[^/]+?.[^/]+?$/, '/');
    
    $('#quiz_container').quiz({
         quizJson: pathJson + "quiz.json",

        onResults: function(good, total){
            
            var perc = good / total;
            
            var alert = $('&lt;div class=&quot;alert&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;')
                .prependTo($(this).find('#quiz_body'));
            
            if(perc == 0){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-danger')
                    .html('All wrong! You didn't get an answer right. Go take up knitting!');
            } else if(perc &gt; 0 &amp;&amp; perc &lt;= 0.25){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-danger')
                    .html('Poor result! You only got ' + good + ' out of ' + total + ' answers right. Please try again.');
            } else if(perc &gt; 0.25 &amp;&amp; perc &lt;= 0.5){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-danger')
                    .html('Just enough! You got ' + good + ' out of ' + total + ' answers right. You can do better.');
            } else if(perc &gt; 0.5 &amp;&amp; perc &lt;= 0.75){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-success')
                    .html('Decent result! You got ' + good + ' out of ' + total + ' answers right. Please try again.');
            } else if(perc &gt; 0.75 &amp;&amp; perc &lt; 1){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-success')
                    .html('Good result! You got ' + good + ' out of ' + total + ' answers right. I think we're nearly there.');
            } else if(perc == 1){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-success')
                    .html('Congratulations, you have answered all the questions!');
            }
        }
    }); 
});
&lt;/script&gt;</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- footer -->
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bg-footer">© 2022 Reload - Laboratorio multimediale. All rights reserved.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- scripts --> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="../dist/jquery.quiz.js"></script> 
<script src="../dist/i18n/messages_it.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var pathJson = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]+?\.[^\/]+?$/, '/');
    
    $('#quiz_container').quiz({
        quizJson: pathJson + "quiz.json",
        onResults: function(good, total){
            
            var perc = good / total;
            
            var alert = $('<div class="alert"></div>')
                .prependTo($(this).find('#quiz_body'));
            
            if(perc == 0){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-danger')
                    .html('All wrong! You didn\'t get an answer right. Go take up knitting!');
            } else if(perc > 0 && perc <= 0.25){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-danger')
                    .html('Poor result! You only got ' + good + ' out of ' + total + ' answers right. Please try again.');
            } else if(perc > 0.25 && perc <= 0.5){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-danger')
                    .html('Just enough! You got ' + good + ' out of ' + total + ' answers right. You can do better.');
            } else if(perc > 0.5 && perc <= 0.75){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-success')
                    .html('Decent result! You got ' + good + ' out of ' + total + ' answers right. Please try again.');
            } else if(perc > 0.75 && perc < 1){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-success')
                    .html('Good result! You got ' + good + ' out of ' + total + ' answers right. I think we\'re nearly there.');
            } else if(perc == 1){
                
                alert.addClass('alert-success')
                    .html('Congratulations, you have answered all the questions!');
            }
        }
    }); 
});
</script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js?lang=javascript&amp;skin=sons-of-obsidian"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Vieira, si es posible. ¿Que has intentado? Por favor utiliza la opción [edit] para agregar tu código PHP. No importa si no funciona, necesitamos ver tu consulta y como estas imprimiendo los datos.